# Where are the holes in my IF conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, plsql, race-condition

***Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production***

I recently joined a project where my main job is to clear a giant backlog of defects. One of those defects is an unwanted duplication of records. I've tracked down the culprit(s) to be...

1. the absense of a unique constraint on the appropriate columns of the
   table
2. an elusive *[Heisenbug](http://bit.ly/HeisenbuggingMeToDeath)* in the PL/SQL at the point in one legacy
   routine where an INSERT is executed.

It is acceptable to the business to enforce the proposed unique constraint in the development and test environment dbs. But for various reasons, it is not acceptable to enforce the unique constraint in the production db. Because of that, I've also proposed as a solution the introduction of a couple of helper routines intended to act as «*Big Burly Bouncers*» at the INSERT point. The intention is for these proposed «*gatekeeper*» routines to programatically prevent duplicates by «*remembering*» what was already INSERTed then only allowing INSERTs if a record with the current id cannot be accounted for in the aforementioned «*memory*».

I've unit tested the hell out of these routines. I've unit tested them in isolation (*each one on its own*). And I've unit tested them with the «*prevent_duplicates()*» calling the «*already_exists()*» routine. These two I've unit tested in both pure PL/SQL and through Java (*[using Spring's StoredProcedure abstraction](http://bit.ly/SpringSprocs)*). I've also unit tested in pure PL/SQL the original «*legacy*» routine refactored to call «*prevent_duplicates()*» which in turn calls «*already_exists()*». In each and every one of my unit tests, all the routines successfully do what I expect.

However, it is only when the routines are called remotely from the webapp that duplicates manage to get through the IF checks in «*prevent_duplicates()*». I've pasted a snippet of the stacktrace at the bottom of post.

So maybe my problem is centered around what I am expecting. Maybe I am too close to the problem and I might be therefore making some naïve assumptions that fresh eyes (*and more knowledgable PL/SQLers*) might be able to spot at first glance...

```
FUNCTION already_exists (
 p_main_thing IN lorem_ipsum.main_id%TYPE, -- NUMBER(10)
 p_type IN lorem_ipsum.entity_type%TYPE, -- VARCHAR(256) 
 p_location IN lorem_ipsum.another_id%TYPE, -- NUMBER(10)
 p_start IN lorem_ipsum.start_using%TYPE, -- DATE
 p_stop IN lorem_ipsum.stop_using%TYPE -- DATE NULLABLE
 ) RETURN NUMBER AS
  m_counter NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

SELECT count(eg.pk_id) INTO m_counter
    FROM lorem_ipsum eg
    WHERE eg.main_id = p_main_thing
    AND eg.entity_type  = p_type
    AND eg.another_id  = p_location
    AND eg.start_using = p_start
    AND NVL(eg.stop_using, TRUNC(SYSDATE-1000000)) = NVL(p_stop, TRUNC(SYSDATE-    1000000));
    commit;
    IF m_counter > 0 THEN
      RETURN 1; -- TRUE
    ELSE
      RETURN 0; -- FALSE
    END IF; 

END already_exists;


================================================================================
PROCEDURE prevent_duplicates(
 p_main_thing IN lorem_ipsum.main_id%TYPE,
 p_type IN lorem_ipsum.entity_type%TYPE, 
 p_location IN lorem_ipsum.another_id%TYPE, 
 p_start IN lorem_ipsum.start_using%TYPE, 
 p_stop IN lorem_ipsum.stop_using%TYPE,
 p_new_pk_id OUT lorem_ipsum.pk_id%TYPE, -- NUMBER(10)
 p_memory IN OUT NOCOPY short_term_memory ) -- TYPE short_term_memory IS TABLE OF BOOLEAN INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
 IS

 m_new_pk_id lorem_ipsum.pk_id%TYPE;

 BEGIN

 IF ( already_exists(p_main_thing, p_type, p_location, p_start, p_stop ) = 0 ) THEN
   IF ( NOT p_memory.EXISTS( p_main_thing ) ) THEN
        m_new_pk_id := pk_id_seq.nextval; -- allowed in 11g ; but not in 10g or lower
        insert into lorem_ipsum (pk_id, entity_type, another_id, start_using,     stop_using, main_id) values (m_new_pk_id, p_type, p_location, p_start, p_stop,     p_main_thing);
        commit;
        p_memory(p_main_thing) := TRUE;
        -- return the new pk_id to the caller
        p_new_pk_id := m_new_pk_id;
  END IF;
 END IF;

-- EXCEPTION
-- ... trap ORA-00001/raise user-defined exception -20999

END prevent_duplicates;

...
org.hibernate.Session hibernate = ...
...
hibernate.beginTransaction();
String orginalLegacyRoutine = "{call myapp.original_legacy_routine("+parentId+",   666)}";
hibernate.createSQLQuery(orginalLegacyRoutine).executeUpdate();
hibernate.getTransaction().commit();
...
hibernate.close
...
```

...These are some of the assumptions I've codified in the above routines...

- I am assuming that if a SELECT is done within the same Oracle transaction
  that a preceding INSERT was executed seconds earlier, that the SELECT
  would have successfully had a hit on that previously INSERTed
  record—if the values in the SELECT's WHERE clause and in the INSERT's
  values clause are exactly the same.
- I am assuming that «*prevent_duplicates()*» two IF statements are in cahoots with the
  associative array—in which IDs of already-inserted records are «*memorized*».
- I'm assuming that between them they should have determined what has
  already been INSERTed.
- I'm assuming that the INSERT should never be called twice for the
  same values.
- I'm assuming that «*prevent_duplicates()*» IF tests are blocking such a case. But they are not.
- I'm assuming that the SELECT & INSERT are both executed in the
  same transaction as the calling routine, because the original «*legacy*» routine is called from Java within a transaction boundary (*see code block above*)

Also, I'm reproducing the duplication defect on dev and test environment dbs in which I am the one and only user exercising the routines through the calling web app. Indeed, I've been in the office all by my lonesome late in the evenings and on weekends trying to figure this out. So because of that—and  my assumptions about Oracle's promise of READ consistency—I can't see how it would be concurrency-related. I will admit however, that my memory of Oracle's take on isolation levels is a little fuzzy. To the best of my recollection though, I assumed I was covered.

So I need help figuring out what incorrect assumptions I have made. Please? Thank you in advance.

**P.S.** *I'm unable to step through the PL/SQL with a debugger because remote debugging is disabled because of security policies and whatnot in force at the shop I'm working.*

```
...
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 | Jan 16, 2015 8:00:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 | SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 | com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract     dba.stackexchange.com.questions.ask.MyApp dba.stackexchange.com.questions.ask.MyAppRPC.addLoremIpsum(dba.stackexchange.com.questions.ask.LoremIpsum,java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception: org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 | Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:124)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:219)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1310)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:396)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at dba.stackexchange.com.questions.ask.MyAppRPCImpl.addLoremIpsum(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   ... 22 more
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 | Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20999: An attempt to insert lorem_ipsum.pk_id: 47396 violated DEDUPE_UNIQUE constraint with: main_id := 6459 , entity_type := FOO, another_id := 858, start_using := 04-JUL-08, stop_using :=
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 | ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.MYAPP", line 504
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 | ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.MYAPP", line 741
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 | ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.MYAPP", line 538
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 | ORA-06512: at line 1
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 | 
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3665)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1352)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 15   | 2015/01/16 20:00:51 |   ... 30 more
...
```

Comment: That commit in `already_exists` is a bug. The fact that the other procedure commits too is really not obvious from its name, I'd call that a bug too. As for your issue: use constraints. That is the only fool-proof solution.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because the OP was already given the answer on dba.stackexchange.com : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89537/where-are-the-holes-in-my-if-conditions

Comment: Why is a unique constraint not allowed in production?  Is it because there is existing data that violates the constraint that must remain?  If so, there's a way to create constraints that only apply to new data.

Comment: When you are "the one and only user exercising the routines through the calling web app", is the app making a single call to the legacy function; or multiple simultaneous calls, on different sessions from different threads, e.g. via a connection pool? Do you see the error consistently or is it intermittent?

Comment: Sincere thanks for all replies. I'll take the blame for people's apparent confusion - because I didn't state it clearly enough—*evidently*—in my original post: This «*holes in the IF*» deal is happening as a result of ONE single call by ONE single user (*me*) clicking ONE «Save» button ONE time in ONE single deployment of ONE web app).

Comment: ...Though I appreciate folk's feedback on the unique constraint issue, I'm not trying to solve ***that*** problem here ☺ I got that one. I just simply want to understand what incorrect assumptions I've made in regards to the IFs, the SELECT and the INSERT.

Comment: @AlexPoole The «***holes in the IFs***» deal only happens when the «*legacy*» routine is called remotely by the web app. The «*legacy*» routine then in turn calls «*prevent_duplicates()*»...and so on. However, when I call either of the routines from, say, SQLPlus, it works like a champ everytime.

Comment: ...The «***holes in the IFs***» deal is also intermittent in that my IF checks and my «*memory*» accounting sometimes behave as sweetly as they should when «*Save*» is submitted in the web app. Then sometimes not. And for the life of me I cannot figure out what the conditions are that causes the IF tests to fail sometimes and pass sometimes. I can't figure it out because I'm ***assuming*** the SELECT and INSERT are done in the same transaction (*see  «**hibernate**» code  snippet ?*). From that assumption I'm ***assuming*** they're querying from the same Oracle block. Is that not the case?

Comment: ...To avoid any confusion: my IF tests are failing within ONE transaction—started by ONE «*thread of control*». There is no «***Session B***» There is ONLY «***Session A***». So I am ***assuming*** there should be no such interleaving as @AlexPoole diagrammed earlier. Is that an incorrect assumption?

Comment: @deduper - that is certainly the assumption I think you have to challange, as the logic and your testing shows it has to work as you expect for a single session. We don't know quite what the web app is doing of course, so I'm having to make my own assumptions, but there doesn't appear to be any other explanation.

Comment: I didn't go into any detail about the web app, for the same reason that I now realize I shouldn't have even mentioned the duplication/unique constraint issue. B/c just as details about duplicates confused the issue (_which I only mentioned by-the-by_) likewise details about the web app would only draw people's attention away from the ONE question I ***needed*** an answer to. I realize now I should've named my example routine the more generic «*conditionally_insert()*» instead. Maybe then people would not have misread my question as «_What is the best way to prevent duplicates_». Live & Loin ☺

Comment: But your assumptions are correct *for a single session*, and your code will do what you expect for a single session - even if it's not necessarily a good way to do it even then. The assumption that has to be incorrect is the one you didn't initially state, that you're still using a single session when it fails. Your conditional insert, whatever you call it, still isn't going to cope with concurrency. The behaviour of the web app might be out of scope of the question you were trying to ask, but it's still going to come down to how this is being called, really.

Answer (score 4):

You've already tested and convinced yourself (correctly, as far as I can tell) that what you're written works for a single session. So the problem must come from concurrent invocations from simultaneous sessions, as you might get from a multi-threaded web application using multiple connections.

The hole in your logic is that if the routine is called from two sessions you still have a race condition; a small period of time where you can fall between your check and insert, e.g:

```
Session A                     Session B
----------------------------  ----------------------------
calls prevent_duplicates()
                              calls prevent_duplicates()
calls already_exists()
gets zero (false)
                              calls already_exists()
                              gets zero (false)
checks p_memory.exists()
gets false
                              checks p_memory.exists()
                              gets false
performs insert
commits
                              performs insert
                              gets constraint violation
```

---

Some other observations that aren't directly related to the issue you're having...

Your `p_memory` check isn't really adding anything here as its contents will be session-specific anyway; if an insert was done in another session you won't see it, and since the insert would be committed by the time it was put in the collection it wouldn't tell you anything extra even if it was cross-session.

It seems like you are trying to silently prevent the attempted insert of a duplicate. If you were allowed the unique constraint - and I'm assuming this is the one you aren't allowed in live for some reason, and what you've shown is the dev/test version where the constraint is there to find the hole - you could skip the `already_exists` and `p_memory` checks, and just catch and ignore (or log) the ORA-00001. There is a separate debate about the benefits of catch-and-ignore vs. check-before-insert that is going even more off-topic...

But without a unique constraint you have to manually serialise the inserts by locking the whole table, or some other unique token that all sessions can see and attempt to lock, which is likely to affect performance. You'd be reimplementing uniqueness in a less efficient way.

Even further off-topic, you're no closer to understanding or fixing the original Heisenbug, you're just handling it slightly better with potential side-effects, or ignoring it with potential side-effects. If I understand what you're doing, that is. You seem to be trying to hide a defect - that duplicates are being inserted - rather than fix it. You're attempting to work around your unknown issue, which may itself be multi-session related, with a method that is also subject to multi-session issues - just maybe less frequently.

Comment: It's super duper that you took the time to do a code review and all. Thanks boss ☺ Now, an answer to the question that I actually ***did*** ask would be equally welcomed. «*Where are the holes in my IF conditions?*» Remember that one?

Comment: @deduper - the hole is the race condition. You already know this works for a single session, so it's contention between two sessions, which hits that race and that hole.

Comment: Your feedback is super appreciated @AlexPoole. But some of your assumptions miss the mark. I'm already guilty clouding the issue with too much information. So I was hesitant to add this next snippet. But then it occurred to me that it might be useful to somebody else reading this. One thing that raising my user-defined -20009 error gives me that ORA-00001 doesn't is this...`ORA-20999: An attempt to insert lorem_ipsum.pk_id: 47396 violated DEDUPE_UNIQUE constraint with: main_id := 6459 , entity_type := FOO, another_id := 858, start_using := 04-JUL-08, stop_using :=`...

Comment: ... By raising my custom exception, the Java exception mechanism in my web app knows something about the state of the entity when things went awry. Would a plain vanilla ORA-00001 provide that same amount of detail to my Java exceptions? And of course, I could put anything I want as the error message. It doesn't have to just be the properties of the entity. Still not convinced on the usefulness of translating built-in exceptions into custom exceptions?

Comment: @deduper - true, and you could log and re-raise the original exception, or have an error logging table, or whatvever; I guess my assumption was that you're trying to avoid the insert (since it's a conditional insert *8-) and thus wouldn't ever see any exception in the first place. So maybe I'm confusing your proposed solution with the extra stuff you've put in to see why it isn't working.